# e.Graphics.Draw

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have discovered how to paint but do not understand that Graphics is property of class PaintEventArgs..how can property have a method? I thought property can have just set and get blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property is an instance of a class, then it is the class that has the method. Not the property itself.

```
public class A
{
    public B MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

So something like `new A().MyProperty.Dosomething();` is valid.

Comment: It would be rare for a property to be a class. More likely to be an object (i.e. instantiation of a class)

Comment: @spender, ah yes. My wording sucks. Sorry.

Comment: @spender: absolutely correct but we (programmers) are incredibly sloppy with those 2 words. And it rarely leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A property can get or set an object.  That object can have methods.

The Graphics object is being provided to you in the PaintEventArgs, so you CAN draw.